# Download file from another API and return this with buffer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using PortableWebDavLibrary to connect to nextcloud WebDAV API. https://github.com/DecaTec/Portable-WebDAV-Library

My simple controller

```
// GET api/download/Test/pedro.txt
    [HttpGet("{*name}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string name)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            return BadRequest("TEXT ...");
        }
        try
        {
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential("USER", "PASS");
            using (var webDavSession = new WebDavSession(Global.BASE_URL, credentials))
            {
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                stream.SetLength(20971520); // TEST set max size

                var responseStream = await webDavSession.DownloadFileAsync(name, stream);

                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                // Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name.TrimEnd('/').Split("/").Last());
                return new FileStreamResult(stream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"))
                {
                    FileDownloadName = name.TrimEnd('/').Split("/").Last()
                };


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest("TEXT ...");
        }
```

The file is downloaded but before save the file in memory (MemoryStream) and the memory of the process goes up to more than 2/3GB in biggest files.

How i can download while i am getting the file from the another API? similar to a buffer

**Edited 31/12/2017**

Nextcloud allow download a file with a GET request (without webdav), with this the FileStreamResult work good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, your solution with `MemoryStream` will not work well for huge files. You could fix it by saving downloaded content to some temporary file and then uploading it content:

```
var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
var stream = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Create);
await webDavSession.DownloadFileAsync(name, stream);

stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
return new FileStreamResult(stream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"))
{
    FileDownloadName = name.TrimEnd('/').Split("/").Last()
};
```

The problem with this code is that it leaves temporary files on the server. `GetTempFileName()` will throw `IOException` eventually when number of temporary files will reach 65535. To fix this you have to periodically delete old temporary files, either in your controller action or in separate server task.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's not possible write file in temp folder and same time sending him and not waiting to read all file?

Comment: There is a `PushStreamContent` in `System.Net.Http` exactly for this purpose. Unfortunately, there is nothing similar in .Net Core for this moment :(

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you can do what you are asking, as, the `stream` is going to hold the information you need **after** the call to `DownloadFileAsync` has returned successfully. Therefore, you sending anything prior to that happening will not be accurate.